# Logs from Flask in Python using AppInsights not appearing when hosted in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: logging, flask, azure-application-insights

When running my flask app locally, I can use the endpoints and these log messages appear in the Application Insights resource in my Azure Portal.

When running my flask app in a service fabric container, I can use the endpoints from my local machine and get working responses, requests information does appear in Application Insights, but the log messages do not.

Example Code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flasgger import Swagger
from applicationinsights.flask.ext import AppInsights
from config.AppConfig import configure_app

# create Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# configure app from settings
configure_app(app)

# initiate Application Insights - allowing requests, exceptions and logs to be examined in Azure Portal
appinsights = AppInsights(app)

Swagger(app)


# force flushing application insights handler after each request
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    appinsights.flush()
    return response


# api routes
@app.route('/diagnostics', methods=['GET'])
def get_diagnostics():
    """This is a diagnostics endpoint to test connectivity.
    ---
    operationId: get_diagnostics
    produces:
      - application/json
    responses:
      200:
        description: returns ok
        examples:
          {
              "status": "ok"
          }
    """

    app.logger.info('Diagnostics endpoint was used.')

    app.logger.debug('This is a debug log message')
    app.logger.info('This is an information log message')
    app.logger.warn('This is a warning log message')
    app.logger.error('This is an error message')
    app.logger.critical('This is a critical message')

    return jsonify({'status': "ok"}), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = app.config['SERVER_HOST']
    port = int(app.config['SERVER_PORT'])
    app.logger.info('DataScience starting on port %s ... ', port)
    app.run(host, port)
```

The instrumentation key is set in the app config, and as stated, the requests are still showing up in the Azure Portal when run non-locally.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Double-check instrumentation key in Azure portal.. try to get and print instrument key from appInsight instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's definitely the correct instrumentation key, and is reporting logs to the portal when running locally from my VM. It just does not report the logs when running from within the docker container within service fabric.

Comment: May be service fabric blocking application Insights request, better you can raise an issue in application Insight Github report. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e333c3c-1629-49e4-b93e-4ba1ab2bf092/application-insight-telemetry-not-sending-data-correctly